# How to read bytes from a file into a single string using readAllBytes?

Tags: java, file, binary, ascii

I'm taking an algorithms class where we have to implement LZW compression in Java. I decided to use a Trie data structure for this, and I've already implemented the Trie and got it working.

Now, I would like to read the bytes from a file, convert them to padded binary (00000001 instead of 01) and then store them in my Trie. I don't need help for the Trie, but rather for reading the contents of the file.

I've tried using readAllBytes to read the contents, and appending each converted byte to a StringBuilder, but when I do this, I get a StringBuilder full of 48's and 49's. I think my binary data is being converted to ASCII, which I don't want. I simply want a string with 1's and 0's.

I've gotten the method below to work, but it relies on an ArrayList instead of a String. It also doesn't use readAllBytes, and it's very slow. (I was unable to get readAllBytes working, it just gives me an infinite loop). We will be graded on performance.

```
    File file = new File(path);

    ArrayList<String> codes = new ArrayList<String>();

    try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        int singleCharInt;
        while ((singleCharInt = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
            codes.add(Integer.toBinaryString((singleCharInt & 0xFF) + 0x100).substring(1));
        }
    }

    return codes;
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

> all my padded binary values were converted to ASCII! So my string was filled with 48, 49, etc. instead of the original date.

This makes it sound like you want to just read a file. Before you can read it, you'd need to know what charset encoding it is in. You can't tell from either the file or the extension (at least, not usually), you'd have to know. If you don't know, UTF-8 is a good bet, and this is the default for the Files API.

```
Path p = Paths.get("/path/to/file.txt");
String string = Files.readString(p);
```

That's all you need to do. No need to involve `readAllBytes`. If you must (which you really only should if you don't have a file at all but something else in InputStream form):

```
String s;
try (InputStream in = ...) {
    s = new String(in.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

Comment: My mistake, I meant to say "instead of the original data".

Comment: The reason for readAllBytes is because I am implementing LZW compression. I want to read the bytes and convert them to their binary equivalents to store them in a Trie.

Comment: I've edited my question to provide my context and detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` class to produce your final String result.

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
    int singleCharInt;
    while ((singleCharInt = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
        buffer.append(Integer.toBinaryString((singleCharInt & 0xFF) + 0x100));
    }
}

// Result: buffer.toString()
```

Comment: This would be _incredibly slow_.

Comment: The OPs question itself is the problem, not this solution. This is actually exactly what the OP is aksing for, AND it is the fastest. So I would not downvote. It's just that the OP's concept is already broken.

Comment: @JayC667 No, this is incredibly slow: You don't call single `read()` on a raw FileInputStream, it is literally 1000x or more slower than using buffers or reading chunks at a time. Harddisks can't read single bytes, they can only read chunks at a time, so `read()` reads the entire chunk, tosses all data except the one byte. Just.. try it. Right now. On, say, a 1GB file. It'll take ages.

Comment: Again, As i told before, you didn't mention any performance problem in your original posted question (when this answer submitted). So, you must not expect an answer with full consideration. The answer is what you want in your question. If you want anything else, you should edit your question not leave an answer with a downvote!

Comment: @rzwitserloot I know, I know. But even reading single bytes is usually only about 40.000 times slower than bulk operations. That still would not be the major problem in the concept. And it could be easily mitigated by using BufferedInputStream.

Comment: @HosseinMobasher I'm not the one who asked the question; merely somebody who thinks this question will send the asker down the wrong path, and teaches bad habits.

Comment: OK! But, in fact, we are responsible to give the answer that solve the problem and consider the problem's aspects. Taking all into account may cause ambiguity and make the solution more complex to understand. So, we should answer in different complexity; From simple to complex answers.

Anyway, I appreciate your way of thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You can get btyeCode from a file like this;

```
public static byte[] readFileNio(String physicalPath) throwsFileNotFoundException, IOException{ 
  RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile(physicalPath,"r");
  FileChannel inChannel = aFile.getChannel();
  ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((int)inChannel.size());
  inChannel.read(buffer);
  buffer.flip();
  inChannel.close();
  aFile.close();
  return buffer.array();
}
```

then you can write byteCode to any particular place

```
Files.write(newPath, readFileNio(fromPath), StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);
```

for compression use `ZipOutputStream`